# Запустить две команды и выйти с ненулевым кодом, если хоть одна выдала ошибку

Tags: bash

Здравствуйте!

Настраиваю тесты и столкнулся с такой, казалось бы, тривиальной, задачей: запустить две команды тестов, чтобы пользователь видел вывод, и, если хоть одна из них вышла с ненулевым кодом, выйти с ненулевым кодом.

Очевидно, `test_command_1 && test_command_2` не подходит, так как в случае, если `test_command_1` выдаст ошибку, `test_command_2` даже не запустится.

Пока придумал такое решение: `test_command_1; EC1=\"$?\"; test_command_2; EC2=\"$?\"; exit $[$EC1 || $EC2]`, но оно громоздкое и неуклюжее. Можно ли как-то его упростить? Обойтись без переменных?

Comment: Совсем без переменных не обойдешься, тебе где-то надо хранить предыдущий exit code, который иначе перетрется после запуска второй команды.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы попытался так:

```
RESULT=0
test_command_1 || RESULT=1
test_command_2 || RESULT=1
exit $RESULT
```

Но с bash толком не работал, могу напутать.